# variables vary mysteriously

Tags: c, variables, memory

Question: what is causing these values to change randomly?

---

Info:

My Code:

```
int q = nonZero;
for(j = nonZero;j>1;j--)
{
    printf("Top: %i %i\n",j,q);
    qsort(tree,j,sizeof(Node),cmp);
    printf("Bottom: %i %i\n",j,q);
    Node t = {tree[0],tree[1],-1};
    tree[0] = &t;
    tree[1] = tree[j];
    tree[j] = NULL;
}
```

Not a complicated little program. make a node out of the top two nodes on the tree, make that the new top node, resort the array, repeat. I added 'q' in as a debug value, I'm completely clueless as to what exactly is happening. If I try and have it run, j typically starts at 73, which it should, the expected is that it would then be 72,71,70,69,68...3,2 and that q will remain 73 indefinitely. here's my output though:

```
Top: 73 73
Bottom: -796584576 32767
Segmentation fault
```

but thats not all, w/o recompiling, i got:

```
Top: 73 73
Bottom: 0 0
Segmentation fault
```

it consistently would give me one of those two outputs. after several runs I saw that 32767 never changed, the q value, but the j value, here -796584576, was always some different absurdly large negative number. anyone have any idea why on earth it would seem as if qsort was changing my j value, as well as what seems to be a completely unrelated value of q?

Comment: One explanation is that the stack pointer value is getting corrupted.  Use a debugger and double-check that its value is the same before and after the qsort call.

Comment: A complete example would be good.  You leave us guessing and inferring the data types of your variables and the possible side-effects of cmp().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `qsort()` call suggests that `tree[]` is an array of `Node`s, but the statement `tree[0] = &t;` rather suggests that it is an array of pointers.  That being then case then:

```
qsort( tree, j, sizeof(&Node), cmp ) ;
```

or better

```
qsort( tree, j, sizeof(*tree), cmp ) ;
```

the latter ensures the size is the sizeof whatever tree is an array of regardless of its type and is therefore safer and more maintainable.

Assigning the address of `t` to a variable with greater scope than `t` is also doomed.

Comment: aaaah. so the size there is the size of the whole array or the size of each element?

Comment: @Narc: it is the size of each element.  That is required for qsort to know what size object to move while not being type specific. The function is well documented in many places.  [A particularly clear documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/qsort/).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if it's your problem, but since `t` is a local variable, it will go out of scope at the end of that loop, and so assigning it to `tree[0]` makes `tree[0]` undefined.

Comment: no, not my problem. the problem lies entirely with q and j. particularly q. i commented out everything that had to do with t and no change, with the exception that now it will throws segmentation errors from between top and bottom.

Comment: @Narcolapser: you don't know where the compiler may choose to store j and q or some other temporary variables. At the beginning of the loop body they may be exactly where t was last time. And then you can sort that location and corrupt them.

Comment: @Narc:  It may not be the problem you are asking about, but it is still incorrect. `t` is no longer in scope after the followinhg `}` but the memory may still be referenced through `tree[0]`, when the memory is likley to be used by somethiong else.  The tree may consequently become corrupted and any action dependent on tehe content of tree[0] is likley to be incorrect.

Comment: but j and q are not temporaries, they are locals, both are declared out side the loop, j is actually used in an earlier loop. I kind of get why it might be the case that if i declared it in the loop it might get over written, but even then, I don't see why the compiler would ever choose to overwrite a variable that is still being used (I know this can happen with pointers, but these are ints, not pointers). that seems like an incredibly bad way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

`t` is a local variable who's lifetime ends with the end of each iteration. So keeping an address of that beyond that iteration is undefined behavior. You have to allocate copies of tree nodes with `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

qsort is corrupting memory.  If this is a qsort you wrote, it could have an error that writes to an invalid place.  If this is a library qsort, it is probably a recursive function that overflows the stack, corrupting your local vars.

Comment: it is the stdlib qsort. how would you advise fixing it so that it corrupt my memory? I hear your argument of overflowing the stack, but I've got 6gb of ram free, I don't really see how it a recursive call >73 times could do that...

Comment: your computer has 6GB, but the OS gives your program some fixed (much smaller) memory for its stack.  How to change this depends on what OS you are using.

Comment: @Narcolapser: Regardless of how much RAM you have, the ammount allocated to the stack of any single process or thread is much less.  In Win32 typically 2Mb.  That said, while the qsort() call is causing the corruption it has more to do with the validiity of the arguments you are passing and almost certainly nothing to do with stack or recursion.

Comment: I agree with Clifford, you do need to worry about stack if you are doing lots of recursion.  But in this case you have bigger problems with arguments.

Comment: @Clifford Ubuntu 64. but it doesn't really matter at this point. xD

Comment: @Narcolapser:  The stack-per thread/process is still relatively small, regardless of OS; that was just illustrative.